# How do you make nth-child work with descendant selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code.

```
    <div class="myDiv">
      <div>
        I want to be red.
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>I'm some other content on the page</p>

    <div class="myDiv">
      <div>
        I want to be blue.
      </div>
    </div>

   .myDiv div:nth-child(odd) {
      color: red;
   }

   .myDiv div:nth-child(even) {
      color: blue;
   }
```

I see why it's not working. It's making every odd div *within* myDiv be red. What I want it to do is make every odd example of a div within myDiv be red. How can I write that?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvKRL/).

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? I am having a hard time understanding what you want. "What I want it to do is make every odd example of a div within myDiv be red." does not make sense to me.

Comment: @jefffabiny, yeah, it's hard to explain, but if you look at the JS Fiddle I think it makes sense. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @jefffabiny, I was hoping for a pure CSS solution. As it appears that isn't possible, I think it's better to make two new CSS classes and place them on alternating divs.

Comment: @lala : A pure ᴄꜱꜱ solution is definitely possible. You don’t even need to use a ᴄꜱꜱ class in your ʜᴛᴍʟ. See my answer.

Comment: @BoltClock, you should reconsider your selection of the correct answer.

Comment: @BBaysinger I think you mean me. But good point. Here I am, 7 years after asking the question, re-selecting the correct answer. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.  The `:nth-child` is on the wrong element.  The inner divs are always the first child, so the `:nth-child(odd)` selector works for both.  Instead move to

```
.myDiv:nth-child(odd) div
```

...***however*** this does not work either because of the `<p>`.  A working solution with your sample is

```
.myDiv:nth-of-type(odd) div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvKRL/1/

***NOTE*** that the `nth-of-type` only works because the `.myDiv` elements are all divs (it's based on the element, not the selector), so the selector ignores the `<p>`.  If there can be another div between `.myDiv`s I don't think any CSS will work for what you want to do.

Comment: Gold! I almost gave up after I read the accepted "it's not possible" answer. But, here we are with a working solution. I salute your solution, sir.

Comment: Thank you so much. I learned something new from this.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this generically, for the reason given by Domenic. To put it simply: there's no selector that lets you filter an existing subset of matched elements.

On the off chance that among your `p` and `div.myDiv` siblings the only `div` elements are the ones with that class anyway, then you could use `:nth-of-type()` to have it look at those intermediate `div`s only:

```
div.myDiv:nth-of-type(odd) div {
    color: red;
}

div.myDiv:nth-of-type(even) div {
    color: blue;
}
```

Or if there are other `div`s without that class which should be excluded, then unless there is some sort of pattern in which they're laid out, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. There is no CSS selector that will do what you want, as you can see by perusing the [complete list of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

In general CSS selectors do not "reach out" to encompass elements above the DOM tree of the one selected. You are asking for something even more sophisticated than that, combining characteristics of parent elements with ordinal properties of the targeted elements, even though those targeted elements are distributed among entirely different places in the DOM tree.

Comment: **Wrong !** In that specific case, it is definetely possible. See my answer.

Comment: This answer is tagged as correct but as other answers below clearly show this is possible.

Answer (score -2):

Just apply`nth-child`to the first member of the descendant selector, not the last one.

```css
div:nth-of-type(odd) > div {
  color: red;
}
div:nth-of-type(even) > div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <div>
    I want to be red.
  </div>
</div>

<p>I'm some other content on the page</p>

<div class="myDiv">
  <div>
    I want to be blue.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants. "every odd example of a div within myDiv be red" not "every div within an odd myDiv". You can see the difference for myDivs containing more than one div.

It's also a duplicate of the other two answers besides mine, both of which do a good job explaining why it doesn't solve the OP's problem but instead a slightly-related one.